# Questions of wireshark packet capturing(promiscuous vs monitor mode)

Tags: wifi, wireshark, packet-capture

After setting up promiscuous mode on my wlan card, I started capturing packets with wireshark. But only broadcast packets or packets destined to my localhost were captured. I cannot find the reason why.

Also, after changing to monitor mode, captured packets all had 802.11 headers unlike promiscuous mode where Ethernet frames were captured. I know devices communicate with 802.11 protocols when wireless. But how is it possible that packets captured in wireshark is displayed in Ethernet frames? (when not in monitor mode)